# RenderSection defined but not rendered

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to have the navigation bars for my website to be a little dynamic.
If a categoryId is equals to 0 I remove some buttons, else I display them all:

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logindisplay">
                @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
            </div>     
            <div id="menucontainer">
                @if (IsSectionDefined("Navigation"))
                {
                    {RenderSection("Navigation", false);}
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>No navigation setup!</p>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="contentwrapper">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Index.cshtml:** from my HomeController

```
@model Project2.ViewModels.ProjectCategoryListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@section Navigation {
    @{Html.RenderAction("LayoutNav", "Home", new { CategoryId = 0 });}
}

<!-- Rest of the page's code -->
```

**Index.cshtml:** from my CategoryController

```
@model Project2.ViewModels.Categories.CategoryIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Category Index";
}

@section Navigation {
    @{Html.RenderAction("LayoutNav", "Home", new { CategoryId = Model.Category.Id });} 
}

<!-- Rest of the page's code -->
```

I tried the exact same setup but without RenderAction and just entering html directly but I keep getting this error message:

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Navigation".
```

The Index actions in the Category and Home controller are straight forward ActionResults that return a View.

Any ideas what's going on there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax error with your RenderSection.  Give this a try:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Navigation"))
{
    @RenderSection("Navigation", false)
}
else
{
    <p>No navigation setup!</p>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post with a helper method for specifying default content in a RenderSection call: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/05/defining-default-content-for-a-razor-layout-section.aspx

It would let you do the following:

```
@RenderSection("Navigation", @<p>No navigation setup!</p>)
```

Comment: Oh that's a neat one! Thanks :)